# how to query xml to find a node value in an xml with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

From the below xml how to find a node exists with value docx and attribute indexed = 1?
I don't want to use loop and this need to be done in JavaScript

```
<docs>
  <doc>
    <name indexed='1'>doc</name>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <name indexed='1'>xls</name>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <name indexed='0'>xlsx</name>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <name indexed='1'>docx</name>
  </doc>
  ..
  ..
</docs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your platform is a web browser you can use jQuery:

```javascript
var xml = '<docs>\n<doc>\n<name indexed="1">doc</name>...</docs>';
var docxIndexed1 = $(':contains("docx")', xml).find('[indexed=1]');

docxIndexed1; // => [ <name indexed=​"1">​docx​</name>​ ]
```

Or if you do not want to use jQuery and only the [built in `DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser):

```javascript
var xml = '<docs>\n<doc>\n<name indexed="1">doc</name>...</docs>'
  , parser = new DOMParser()
  , doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml')
  , elements = [].slice.apply(doc.getElementsByTagName('*'));
var docxIndexed1 = elements.filter(function(x) {
  return (x.textContent === 'docx') && (x.getAttribute('indexed') === '1')
});

docxIndexed1; // => [ <name indexed=​"1">​docx​</name>​ ]
```